# Pandas create column with accumulated link history sorted by timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
UserId| links  | timestamp
---------------------------
user1 | link1  | 1624245350
user2 | link23 | 1624255350
user2 | link15 | 1624235250
user1 | link12 | 1624245250
user1 | link20 | 1624245150
user2 | link1  | 1624234150
user3 | link15 | 1624235550
user2 | link34 | 1624235152
user3 | link1  | 1624231234
user1 | link16 | 1614245350
```

I need to transform the above to the following dataFrame below. Note, each user will need to be sorted by timestamp with a new column called linkHistory. linkHistory is an accumulation of links that the user has clicked on in the past before they clicked on the current link shown in the **links** column. Hence, the first linkHistory for every user should be an empty string.

```
UserId| links  | timestamp   |  linkHistory 
------------------------------------------
user1 | link16 | 1614245350  | ''
user1 | link20 | 1624245150  | link16
user1 | link12 | 1624245250  | link16 link20
user1 | link1  | 1624245350  | link16 link20 link12 
user2 | link1  | 1624234150  | ''
user2 | link15 | 1624235250  | link1
user2 | link23 | 1624255350  | link1 link15
user3 | link1  | 1624231234  | ''
user3 | link15 | 1624235550  | link1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can first [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by `UserId` and `timestamp` to get in the correct order. Then [`groupby shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) to offset the each group by one row. Lastly, use [`groupby expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#window-and-resample-operations) to create an iterable to `' '.join` the "previous" `links` values:

```
# Get In Correct Order
df = df.sort_values(['UserId', 'timestamp'], ignore_index=True)
# Join Previous links per group
df['linkHistory'] = [
    ' '.join(g.iloc[1:]) for g in
    df.groupby('UserId')['links'].shift(fill_value='')  # Offset Links
        .groupby(df['UserId']).expanding()  # Create Expanding Window to join
]
```

This can also be done in a few steps instead of a single comprehension:

```
# Get In Correct Order
df = df.sort_values(['UserId', 'timestamp'], ignore_index=True)
# Reuse Grouper
grouper = df.groupby('UserId')
# Offset Links
df['linkHistory'] = grouper['links'].shift(fill_value='')
# Create Expanding Window to join
df['linkHistory'] = [' '.join(grp_history.iloc[1:])
                     for grp_history in grouper['linkHistory'].expanding()]
```

`df`:

```
  UserId   links   timestamp            linkHistory
0  user1  link16  1614245350                       
1  user1  link20  1624245150                 link16
2  user1  link12  1624245250          link16 link20
3  user1   link1  1624245350   link16 link20 link12
4  user2   link1  1624234150                       
5  user2  link34  1624235152                  link1
6  user2  link15  1624235250           link1 link34
7  user2  link23  1624255350    link1 link34 link15
8  user3   link1  1624231234                       
9  user3  link15  1624235550                  link1
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'UserId': ['user1', 'user2', 'user2', 'user1', 'user1', 'user2', 'user3',
               'user2', 'user3', 'user1'],
    'links': ['link1', 'link23', 'link15', 'link12', 'link20', 'link1',
              'link15', 'link34', 'link1', 'link16'],
    'timestamp': [1624245350, 1624255350, 1624235250, 1624245250, 1624245150,
                  1624234150, 1624235550, 1624235152, 1624231234, 1614245350]
})
```

Comment: Awesome! This is an elegant solution!

Comment: I am getting this error when I run your code: NotImplementedError: See issue #11704 https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11704

Comment: Expanding windows are iterable in versions 1.1.0 and newer. [ENH: Implement __iter__ for Rolling and Expanding #34201](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/34201) also in the release notes [What’s new in 1.1.0 (July 28, 2020)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#other-enhancements)